# compare rows in dataframes with unordered columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes, each row represent an "object" made of an id and the object attributes.
So:

| id | att1 | att2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | value11 | value12 | ... |
| ID2 | value12 | value22 | ... |

The attributes are unordered, and I want to know if the 2 dataframes are equal or which are the differences.

So for example this rows should be considered equal: (1,1,2) and (1,2,1).
The dataframe size is about thousand of row and hundred of columns.

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Values and ID can be string, not necessarily numeric

Comment: Is order of attributes consistent across rows in the same dataframe?

Comment: You have 2 dataframes. I suppose the common key is `id` and all other columns are a list of attributes to compare?

Comment: no, the order in rows doesnt matter. and yes id is the key

Comment: I think the way to do it would be to "sort" all the attributes in each row, and then compare the rows with the same key...but not sure how to write it